# Accessing objects into test when sub directories are created in Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor, pom.xml

I have created a folder called PageObjects and kept all Object relared .js files inside it.

I have created another folder in my project called Sanity and kept my Sanity test case (spec) inside it.

When I am trying to access the page object file from the directory, I am getting the below error.

[image]

My project structure looks like below

[image]

If we keep every js (PageObject, Spec, config) file within core project directory, everything works fine. But, if we use specific directory structure, there is hiccup.

Please advise how we can handle this.

I feel directory structure is more powerful with respect to maintainability.

Can you please advise how I can access Object & Tests which are in separate directories?

Comment: @alecxe - Thank you. I followed the suggestion in that question and able to achieve what I wanted.

Comment: Awesome, sorry I closed it but it felt really like the same problem we had as well. Glad it was useful!

Comment: @alecxe - May I request you to please have a look at - 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53803025/chained-scripts-in-package-json-is-not-executing-properly