# How to run two different wdio.config.js file one after another

Tags: javascript, typescript, selenium, appium, webdriver-io

I currently have two wdio.config.js files with different configurations. How can i run both one after another? Is it possible?

This is how I am defining in the code:

first config.js

```
const { join } = require('path');
require('@babel/register')

exports.config = {
    maxInstances: 3,
    runner: 'local',
    //
    specs: [
        './tests/specs/**/*.spec.js'
    ],
    //
    exclude: [
        // 'path/to/excluded/files'
    ],
    //
    //
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9174/',

    capabilities: {
        chromeBrowser: {
            capabilities: {
                browserName: 'chrome'
            }
        },
        App: {
            port: 4723,
            capabilities: {
                platformName: 'iOS',
                'appium:platformVersion': '12.4',
                'appium:orientation': 'PORTRAIT',
                'appium:noReset': true,
                'appium:newCommandTimeout': 240,
                "appium:platformName": "iOS",
                "appium:deviceName": "iPhone 8",
                "appium:bundleId": "com.app.debug",
            }
        },
    },

    services: ['appium'],
    /* appium: {

        args: {
            address: '127.0.0.1',
        }
    }, */

    //
    //logLevel: 'trace',
    //
    //deprecationWarnings: true,
    //
    //bail: 0,
    //
    waitforTimeout: 20000,
    //
    //connectionRetryTimeout: 90000,
    //
    //connectionRetryCount: 3,
    //
    services: ['selenium-standalone'],
    //
    //framework: 'jasmine',
    /* jasmineNodeOpts: 
    {   
    // Jasmine default timeout
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 60000,
    expectationResultHandler(passed, assertion) 
    {
      // do something
    }, */

    //
    //
}
```

second config.js

```
const { join } = require('path');
require('@babel/register')

exports.config = {
    runner: 'local',
    //
    specs: [
        './tests/specs/**/*.common.js'
    ],
    //
    exclude: [
        // 'path/to/excluded/files'
    ],
    //
    //

    capabilities: {

        App: {
            port: 4724,
            capabilities: {
                platformName: 'iOS',
                'appium:platformVersion': '13.2',
                'appium:orientation': 'PORTRAIT',
                'appium:noReset': true,
                'appium:newCommandTimeout': 240,
                "appium:deviceName": "iPhone 11",
                "appium:bundleId": "com.xyz.debug",
            }
        }
    },

    services: ['appium'],
    /* appium: {

        args: {
            address: '127.0.0.1',
        }
    }, */

    //
    //logLevel: 'trace',
    //
    //deprecationWarnings: true,
    //
    //bail: 0,
    //
    waitforTimeout: 20000,
    //
    //connectionRetryTimeout: 90000,
    //
    //connectionRetryCount: 3,
    //
    services: ['selenium-standalone'],
    //
    //framework: 'jasmine',
    /* jasmineNodeOpts: 
    {   
    // Jasmine default timeout
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 60000,
    expectationResultHandler(passed, assertion) 
    {
      // do something
    }, */

    //
    //
}
```

and my package.json file:

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "name": "appium-boilerplate",
  "version": "5.3.1",
  "description": "Run end to end tests with using the webapp and the mobile app",
  "scripts": {
    "android.sauce.rdc.app": "./node_modules/.bin/wdio ./config/saucelabs/wdio.android.rdc.app.conf.js",
    "consumer.app": "./node_modules/.bin/wdio ./config/wdio.consumer.app.conf.js",
    "android.browser": "./node_modules/.bin/wdio ./config/wdio.android.browser.conf.js",
    "ios.app": "./node_modules/.bin/wdio ./config/wdio.ios.app.conf.js",
    "ios.sauce.rdc.app": "./node_modules/.bin/wdio ./config/saucelabs/wdio.ios.rdc.app.conf.js",
    "ios.browser": "./node_modules/.bin/wdio ./wdio.conf.js",
    "real.browser": "./node_modules/.bin/wdio ./config/wdio.browser.conf.js",
    "lint": "eslint config tests",
    "build": "babel --presets es2015 -d lib/ src"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.7.6",
    "esm": "^3.2.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.7.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/register": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/traverse": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/types": "^7.5.5",
    "@wdio/appium-service": "^5.12.1",
    "@wdio/cli": "^5.12.4",
    "@wdio/jasmine-framework": "^5.16.15",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^5.16.15",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^5.16.15",
    "@wdio/sauce-service": "^5.12.1",
    "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "5.6.4",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^5.16.11",
    "@wdio/sync": "^5.16.15",
    "appium": "^1.13.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.2",
    "chromedriver": "^78.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^7.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-wdio": "^5.12.1",
    "mocha": "^6.2.2",
    "node-fetch": "^2.3.0",
    "spectron": "^9.0.0",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^5.0.2",
    "webdriverio": "^5.12.4"
  }
}
```

I would like to run the first one then the second one with one command. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create individual test command for both config files. Then add a new script in package.json having both the test commands separated by &&.

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53809731/8903949

(Or)

Use gulp or grunt task.

Comment: but how would i add exactly in my case? also will it run after it finished the first one?

Comment: This will execute one after the other for sure. Both are different npm scripts.

Comment: Script test1 will have "wdio config1.js" and test2 will have "wdio config2.js

Comment: but what is test1 and test2 i am little confused

Comment: i tried this but does not work for my code, how can i implement in my code?

Comment: @ Bharath Kumar S, in the last line, is it going to be npm run browser_test or only npm run browser?

Comment: You should run `npm run test` which runs the browser test first and then mobile test.

Comment: is it possible to run the second test even if the first one fails?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same case. I used a shell script file for this case.

For MAC and Linux: create `run.sh` file, then use command `sh run.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
npm run android.sauce.rdc.app
npm run consumer.app
npm run ...
```

For Windows: create `run.bat` file, then run it.

```
npm run android.sauce.rdc.app
npm run consumer.app
npm run ...
```